# Update datetime using .NET and SQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql, sql-server, entity-framework

I have Entity Framework ObjectContext. I need to update column of type datetime.

Here is my code:

```
ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(string.Format("update MyTable set DateTimeField='{0}' where Id = {1}",
                                  myEntity.DateTimeField, IdValue));
```

Why am I getting such exception:

> Submit operation failed. The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value. The Statement has been terminated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand.aspx) takes SqlParameters so  Its better if you use parameterized query like:

```
ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(
    "update MyTable set DateTimeField=@pDateTimeField  where Id = @pID", 
      new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@pDateTimeField", Value =myEntity.DateTimeField  },
      new SqlParameter {ParameterName = "@pID", Value =IdValue });
```

See: [Working with Parameterized Commands - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358758.aspx)

Currently your code is not working because it is considering `DateTime` as string value.

Comment: +1...just pipped me to it! Assuming myEntity.DateTimeField is a DateTime this should just work

Comment: My solution worked out for me but doesn't work on staging. I will check in several minutes..

Answer (score 2):

It looks like myEntity.DateTimeField is a string and not a datetime field.

Comment: No matter what type it is, after it has come through his code `string.Format("some sql '{0}' continue sql", myEntity.DateTimeField)`, surely it is reduced to a substring of some new string. What that substring looks like depends on what override of `ToString()` is hit at runtime (`virtual` method).